# eqnarray and cases

Tags: math-mode

I have quite [a strange tex style](http://eccomas2012.conf.tuwien.ac.at/fileadmin/mediapool-eccomas2012/Diverse/Templates/FullPaper_Instructions_LaTex_ECCOMAS2012.zip) from the conference. Everything is fine, but the following code does not work here:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
a = \begin{cases} 1 \\
                  2
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}
```

does not seem to work here in conjunction with `eqnarray`, which is also required. 
Is it possible to mimic the behaviour of cases in this `case`?

Comment: I threw that into the tex file contained in your link and it seemed to produce the correct output after adding `\usepackage{amsmath}` to the preamble.  Have you loaded `amsmath`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`eqnarray` is not required in order for `cases` to work. Moreover, it's deprecated in terms of its support/usage and should therefore not be used. Rather use `align` (see [`\eqnarray` *vs* `\align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764). You're most likely after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  a = \begin{cases}
      x & \text{if $y=1$} \\
      z & \text{if $b=2$}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `cases` as well as `\text` and `align`, although `align` is technically not needed for such an elementary equation. Using an `equation` environment (or unnumbered `\[` ... `\]`) would suffice.

You could also obtain the above output *manually* using

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  a = \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{\quad}l}
      x & \mbox{if $y=1$} \\[\jot]
      z & \mbox{if $b=2$}
    \end{array}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use a simple `\[...\]`? `align` is not needed here!

Comment: @HendrikVogt: That's correct. In the spirit of the original question, I kept the align. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Werner The original question uses `eqnarray` where it shouldn't to begin with, because there's no alignment. The "correct" answer would use `equation`.