# Boxing multiple equation

Tags: equations

```
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\sigma_{ann} \propto \begin{cases}
\frac{\lambda_3^2 m_b^2}{m_H^4} & \text{$m_S\ll\frac{m_H}{2}$}\\ \\
\frac{\lambda_3^2 m_b^2}{m_H^2 \Gamma_H^2} &\text{$m_S=\frac{m_H}{2}$}\\ \\
\frac{\lambda_3^2 m_b^2}{m_H^2 \Gamma_H^2} &\text{$m_S=\frac{m_H}{2}$}
\end{cases}}
\end{equation}
```

This is giving following output-
[image]

But i want my output to look like this

[image]
where size of fractions inside curly bracket is larger.

Comment: you can do this with `\begin{equation}
\boxed{...}
\end{equation}`

Comment: @touhami Maybe you should add that **\boxed** is a command from the **amsmath** package afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the "displaystyle", i.e., large, fractional expressions to the right of the curly brace, either use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` or employ the `dcases` environment (requires the `mathtools` package) instead of the "basic" `cases` environment. As the other comments and answers have already noted, used `\boxed` to enclose the equation in a rectangular frame.

By the way, the `\text{$...$}` wrappers are unnecessary; just write out the argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases' environment
\begin{document} 
\begin{equation}
\boxed{
\sigma_{\mathrm{ann}} \propto 
\begin{dcases}
\frac{\lambda_3^2 m_b^2}{m_H^4}           & m_S\ll\frac{m_H}{2}\\[1ex]
\frac{\lambda_3^2 m_b^2}{m_H^2\Gamma_H^2} & m_S=\frac{m_H}{2}\\[1ex]
\frac{\lambda_3^2 m_b^2}{m_H^2\Gamma_H^2} & m_S=\frac{m_H}{2}
\end{dcases}
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Answer to the updated question

Regarding the **frac** part of the question:

- If you use the **amsmath** package then you can use **\dfrac** instead  of **\frac**.
- This will make is larger.
- **displaystyle** - hence the **d** in **\dfrac** - is the technical term I think.

## Answer to the original question

> Normally you should show some effort of your own or at least provide a
>   so called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). But you are new and probably don't know that.

What you ask for is called **cases** environment (boxed version) - see the following related questions/answers for example:

- [Using "cases" inside "equation" gives error[with "amsmath" loaded]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67702)
- [eqnarray and cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63415)
- [How to write cases with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240868)
- [How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47170) (with an answer with 91 upvotes currently)
- [Large braces for specifying values of variables by condition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9065)

There is even a **tag** ([What is a tag?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_(metadata))) for **cases**:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cases

**Boxed equations** are also easy to find - here are some related questions/answers:

- [How to make a box around an equation in align-environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193242)
- [How can I box multiple aligned equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109900)
- [Equations and Equation Numbers within a Box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268025/)

Comment: So is this question a duplicate then?

Comment: @Werner Yes, I think so (2 duplicated I guess, **cases** and **boxed equation**).

Comment: If you have *a* duplicate, then vote-to-close.

Comment: @Werner Done...

Comment: I have edited the question.